# Android: not able to cutomise action menu style

Tags: android, menu

We are not able to style the actionmenu items in our app, tried setting the style in different ways. We are using androidx libraries. Please let us know what we might be doing wrong. Appreciate your help.

```
<style name="MenuTextStyle" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Menu">
    <item name="android:textColor">#F0F</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">normal</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">10sp</item>
</style>

<style name="AppThemeMm" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item> //This works
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item> //This works
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item> //This works
    <item name="android:actionMenuTextAppearance">@style/MenuTextStyle</item> //This does not work
</style>
```

Comment: try without android prefix like   `<item name="actionMenuTextAppearance">@style/MenuTextStyle</item>`

Comment: Tried now, but no luck

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="android:dropDownListViewStyle">@style/actionMenuDropDown</item>
    <item name="android:listPreferredItemHeightSmall">50dp</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>

</style>
    <style name="actionMenuDropDown" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ListView.DropDown">
    <item name="android:divider">#5A5252</item>
    <item name="android:dividerHeight">1sp</item>
    <item name="android:listSelector">#FFEA00</item>
    <item name="android:background">#AC2299</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#443A43</item>
</style>
```

If you are using PopupOverlay text color will not change. But you can override the text color like this

```
 <style name="AppTheme.MyPopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark" >
    <item name="android:textColor">#AC5532</item>
</style>
```

And use it like this

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.MyPopupOverlay" />
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I customised PopupOverlay and that worked for me

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for us. Added customisation directly to PopupOverlay.

```
<style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">14sp</item>
</style>
```

In the custom toolbar

app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"